# Xamarim form document scanner

Tags: forms, xamarin, document, scanning

I am trying to implement the document scanner in Xamarin form but I am not finding any open source library or code reference for same. There are couple of paid library are available but I don't want to use that.

Kindly let me if someone has completed document scanning in Xamarin form.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/enginkirmaci/Imaging-Library/tree/master/samples/Xamarin/EdgeDetection.Forms

Comment: Please have  look at it. Maybe usefull

Comment: https://github.com/enginkirmaci/Imaging-Library

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have used the Imaging Library in Xamarin form android but performance is very slow. its taking more than a minute to convert. Sometime output is also not correct.

Comment: You could try to use `ImageSDK.Pixelnetica` and `Pixelnetica.DSSDK.Xamarin.iOS` for the Document Scanning SDK.